# After submit stay on same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

After press the Form Submit button the page goes .scrollTop ... How to Stop that in this code bellow ?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(i) {
  "use strict";
  (i.wc_product_vendors_vendor_frontend = {
    init: function() {
      var s = i(".wcpv-shortcode-registration-form").position();
      i(document.body).on(
        "submit",
        "form.wcpv-shortcode-registration-form",
        function(o) {
          o.preventDefault();
          var r = {
              action: "wc_product_vendors_registration",
              ajaxRegistrationNonce:
                wcpv_registration_local.ajaxRegistrationNonce,
              form_items: i(this).serialize()
            },
            e = i(this);
          i(".wcpv-registration-message").remove(),
            e.block({
              message: null,
              overlayCSS: { background: "#fff", opacity: 0.6 }
            }),
            i.post(wcpv_registration_local.ajaxurl, r, function(o) {
              if ((e.unblock(), o.length && "success" === o))
                i(document.body).trigger("wcpv_vendor_registration_on_success"),
                  e.before(
                    '<p class="wcpv-shortcode-registration-success wcpv-registration-message">' +
                      wcpv_registration_local.success +
                      "</p>"
                  ),
                  e.fadeOut("fast"),
                  i("input, textarea", e)
                    .not('input[type="submit"]')
                    .val("");
              else {
                var t = "";
                i.each(o.errors, function(o, r) {
                  t += '<span class="error">' + r + "</span>";
                }),
                  e.before(
                    '<div class="wcpv-shortcode-registration-form-errors wcpv-registration-message">' +
                      t +
                      "</div"
                  );
              }
              i("html, body").scrollTop(s.top - 50);
            });
        }
      );
    }
  }),
    i.wc_product_vendors_vendor_frontend.init();
});
```

Comment: it could be the trigger is an anchor with href # hash

Comment: can´t you just remove this part `i("html, body").scrollTop(s.top - 50);` ?